# Hide sheet and go back to previous sheet button

Tags: excel, vba, button

I want to add a button to every sheet on my workbook which hides the active sheet and go back to previous sheet. I've tried the following code but it only goes back to previous sheet. I am not familiar to VBA.

How am I supposed to modify the code so it can hide the active sheet before going back?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Set LstSht = Sh
End Sub


Public LstSht As Worksheet
Sub GoToLast()
    LstSht.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: What should be done if the previous sheet is already hidden? Should it activate the first sheet to the left that is not hidden or just ignore it? What should be done if you're out of sheets to the left?

Comment: I think, a base sheet can be chosen and get it activated using "IF" statement when there is no previous or any other sheet left. But I don't know how? :)

Answer (score 0):

The `.Visible` property of a `WorkSheet` controls if it is hidden or not.  Here is the Microsoft documentation on how to use it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.visible

Comment: Thanks for your answer but could you be more specific? cause I really dont know how to combine these codes. I already have another button on my workbook which hides the sheets with the following code: 

Sub HideSht()
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Visible = False
End Sub

Comment: You have a `Sub` that hides the sheet, and a `Sub` that activates the sheet that you're interested in; good.  All you need to do now is call both of those `Subs`, and you should have what you want.

Comment: I made it but the sub hides the sheet and doesn't go to previous sheet because now the hidden sheet is the previous sheet, i guess :) (it goes to the next sheet automatically). When I change the order of called subs, it goes to previous sheet first and then hides it. It's driving me crazy :)) Thanks a lot for your help but I think I'm gonna give up for today

Answer (score 0):

For those who follow this question; I solved my problem by making a little modification to my codes like this:

- First, go to the previous sheet
- Then, hide the previous sheet (The second step was hiding the active sheet before, now it's the previous sheet)

**You can try this:**

**in ThisWorkbook:**

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
        Set LstSht = Sh
    End Sub
```

**in Modules:**

```
Public LstSht As Worksheet
Private Sub GoToLast()
        LstSht.Activate
End Sub

Private Sub HidePrvSht()
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(LstSht.Name).Visible = False
End Sub

Sub HideNGo()
Call GoToLast
Call HidePrvSht
End Sub
```

Special thanks to **TehDrunkSailor** :)